# routes matching in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new to ruby on rails.

Can anyone please explain about routes in ruby on rails.

```
         example:
        match 'dash_bw' :to 'reports#dash_bw'
```

How it link to controller,can please explain.
`'report#dash_bw'` Here we writing class name that define in controller, is it write ?
If it wrong please explain  how it link to controller and view.
please don't mind i am learning, my own please explain .
right side of routes match is class name or directory name.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the route should look like:

```
match 'dash_bw',  to: 'reports#dash_bw', via: :get
```

which will create a route like

```
dash_bw GET    /dash_bw(.:format)                   reports#dash_bw
```

You can check the routes by running `rake routes` command.

When you access `http://yourdomain.com/dash_bw` in the browser **which will call `dash_bw` action in your `ReportsController`** (because of **reports#dash_bw**).

Also, you could also use the new way to define the routes as:

```
 get 'dash_bw', to: 'reports#dash_bw', as: :dash_bw
```

> Here we writing class name that define in controller, is it write ?

To answer the above question, you specify the *class name* of the controller, but not the complete name just the prefix part before the `Controller`.

For example: if your controller name is `ReportsController` then you specify `reports`(in lower case) in your `to:` option i.e., `to: reports#dash_bw` part. Please note that `dash_bw` is your `action` name.

Answer (score 0):

```
'reports#dash_bw'
```

refers to Reports Controller, dash_bw Action.

You must have a controller like:

```
class ReportsController...

    def dash_bw
    ... code here
    end
end
```

So when the browser hits that route what ends up happening is the dash_bw method gets called.